# Session variables not loading in time

Tags: php, session

I have a PHP code with 2 pages.

Page 1: allows for loading of variable inputs into several arrays and then into several SESSION variables created using these arrays.

Page 2: creates and displays a png utilizing all the SESSION variables and using “imagecreate”.

Sometimes, randomly, page 2 does not always load all the SESSION variables before the pgn is created, leading to a malformed image.

Refreshing page 2 then creates the correct image, confirming that all the SESSION variables are finally being passed to page 2.

Can the png creation be delayed until after all SESSION variables are loaded or is there another solution?

Comment: What is a pgn?  ... do you mean png?  Also, it will be very helpful to see the code of your two scripts to see your session handling.

Comment: I think Ozzie meant png image file not "pgn". And all those down voters, give Ozzie a break, it his/her first post. At least comment as to why you voted it down so he/she can improve.

Comment: PHP sessions ensure there's no concurrency, so if page 1 is loaded before page 2, the data will be there. But if you call both pages at the same time there is no guarantee whatsoever of which one will be loaded first. It seems to me the problem is not the session but simply you not ensuring things are loaded in order.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use SESSION variable for such data as your question states

> variable inputs into several arrays and then into several SESSION variables created using these arrays.

As your traffic grows you will run out of disk space if you store a large data for each user in your session storage.

Instead of `SESSION` variable use `localStorage` of your user's browser for your need, they'll be faster and much less load on your disk space.

Comment: I agree SESSION variable should not be used but am curious as to why they are not being read properly by page 2? As mentioned above, some code from Ozzie would help.

Comment: As your page is getting rendered before your server has completed it is processing, the more variables you put there the more time It takes for the server to process it so more delayed is your response and with a few items being unprocessed

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the replies.
The problem was not loading the SESSION variables, it was loading the cached image rather than the newly created image.
Included a timestamp in the image name and this solved the problem.
i.e $plan[time()] = imagecreatetruecolor( 1000, 1000 );